# Why isn't mysql query matching during login?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, hash

I can't figure out why the password isn't matching when attempting to login after activation. I've trimmed down the pasted code below for ease of viewing.

Here is the relevant registration code:

```
$salt = substr(sha1(uniqid(rand(),true)),0,20);
$password_db = hash('sha256', $salt.$password1);

$sqlinfo = mysql_query("INSERT INTO db_1 (email, password, salt)
VALUES('$email1','$password_db','$salt')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Here is the correlating code for login:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sqlinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_1 WHERE email='$email' AND emailactiv='1'"); 

if($sqlinfo['password'] == hash('sha256', $sqlinfo['salt'].$password)){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlinfo)){
    ... }
    else { ...
```

I've done several iterations thus far to no avail. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/mysql_query + `var_dump($sqlinfo);`

Comment: why are you using a while loop to check if the password matches, why not extend your `WHERE` with `AND password = '". $password."' `

Comment: Let me introduce you to a friend of mine called [Bobby Tables](http://www.bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @zeshin your code is vulnerable to SQL Injections. Please read the bobby tables link above if you don't wanna get hacked.

Comment: (While the use of a large random salt is a good start, SHA is vulnerable to brute-force attacks as it is *too fast*. Although I would consider that secondary to the SQL injection vulnerabilities .. best/easiest just to use a well-vetted *existing* auth system.)

Comment: thanks, i suppose i should have included more of the code. i am, of course, using mysql_real_escape_string on all user inputs.

Comment: You should at least use ***`mysqli_real_escape_string`***, along with all of the **MySQLi** functions. **`mysql` is deprecated.** *MySQLi* stands for *MySQL Improved*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sqlinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_1 WHERE email='$email' AND emailactiv='1'"); 

//You need to first fetch data before using it.
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sqlinfo)) {

    //Now you can use the data
    if($result['password'] == hash('sha256', $result['salt'].$password)){
         //matched... login correct
    } else {
         //not matched.. invalid login
    }
}
...
```

Hope it's self-explanatory.
You missed one very important line!

BTW, stop using mysql_* functions as they are deprecated, use PDO or mysqli_*

EDIT: Please try now. I thought it can only hold one value (for login purpose)

Comment: this does not work if the query had multiple results, it only works when the first row contains the password. Unless the email column is unique...

Answer (score 1):

you code, currently, is vulnerable with SQL injection. One suggestion is to reformat your code using **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** or **[MySQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)**.

Example of PDO:

```
<?php

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM db_1 WHERE email = ? AND emailactiv=? ");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $email);
$stmt->bindParam(2, 1);

$stmt->execute();

?>
```

you didn't fetch the row that's why it's not matching anything.
add this line before the `IF` statement:

```
$rowHere = mysql_fetch_row($sqlinfo);
```

and use `$rowHere` in your `IF` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).

Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

And you need to 'sanitize your inputs' (a common phrase) to avoid SQL injection, using [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

See the [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com) link as per the comments on the question.